# Crate gt212 footswitch

Tags: electric-guitar

I have a Crate gt212 and am looking for a footswitch for it. Can't seem to find a Crate one anywhere. Will [this Apex 3 button](https://www.long-mcquade.com/1772/Guitars/Parts/Apex_Electronics/Three_Button_Footswitch.htm?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIuqCXz9eo7wIVAYTICh1ZmgxJEAQYASABEgL7VvD_BwE) switch work with it?

Comment: I may have answered my own question. Was reading a review that says it's the same as the stock Crate switch. If anyone has any other info on it, thanks in advance